# How can I use Methods in digitalWrite(): digitalWrite(int, "methodHere")?

Tags: arduino-ide, simulator

When creating a piece of code to operate a 7-segment display, I ran into a problem:

The seven segment display on TinkerCad (I was using this at the time) requires you to pull down the inputs to turn a segment on, while the one that I have turns on when I pull up the inputs.

Instead of completely rewriting the code for the display that I had, I wanted to make my code more universal for if I need to use it in the future.

I cannot find a way to make the method digitalWrite(int pin, int val) work with a method that returns and int in the place of "int val"

This is the code that will not work:

```
int F = 11;
int G = 10;
int E = 9;
int D = 8;
int C = 7;
int DP = 6;
int B = 5;
int A = 4;
int type = 1;

 int highLow(int highOrLow)
{

  int digOutput;

  if(type = 1)
  {

    if(highOrLow = 1)
    {

      digOutput = 1;

    }
    if( highOrLow = 0)
    {

      digOutput = 0;

    }

  }
  if(type = 0)
  {

    if(highOrLow = 0)
    {

       digOutput = 0;

    }
    if( highOrLow = 2)
    {

      digOutput = 1;

    }

  }
  return digOutput;
}

void zero()
{
  digitalWrite(F, highLow(0));
  digitalWrite(G, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(E, LOW);
  digitalWrite(D, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C, LOW);
  digitalWrite(DP, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(B, LOW);
  digitalWrite(A, LOW);
}

setup
{
pinMode(F, OUTPUT);
pinMode(G, OUTPUT);
pinMode(E, OUTPUT);
pinMode(D, OUTPUT);
pinMode(C, OUTPUT);
pinMode(DP, OUTPUT);
pinMode(B, OUTPUT);
pinMode(A, OUTPUT);
zero();
}
```

Note : I am just using pin f to test.

Also, my etiquette is not very well defined or tested, so please keep it rather simple if you can.

If it matters, I am going to be using to using an Arduino Mega2560 produced by Elegoo.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation it is far more efficient to use `#define` and conditional compilation.

```
// Uncomment this for tinkercad
// #define INVERTED

#ifdef INVERTED
#  define ON HIGH
#  define OFF LOW
#else
#  define ON LOW
#  define OFF HIGH
#endif
```

Then just use ON or OFF in place of HIGH and LOW.

```
digitalWrite(3, ON);
```

But the reason you have a problem is not because you are trying to use a function as the value to `digtalWrite()` - the problem is actually in your basic C syntax.

You are using the assignment operator (`=`) when you should be using the comparison operator (`==`). For example here:

```
if(highOrLow = 0)
```

you should have:

```
if(highOrLow == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Will try this when i can get access to a computer again!